# Trying to get a nested JSON using Oracle & SQL

Tags: sql, json, oracle

So my organization is making a switch to a cloud based company for our work-order system.  I have been working on our standard data connectors for a little while now & keep coming up short of my desired outcome.

This is my current SQL:

```
select oo.campus_desc AS INSTITUTION,
                   f.organization_level_6 AS ORGANIZATION,
                   f.organization_mc_desc AS ORG_DESC,
                   min(f.dept) AS DEPARTMENT 

from odsmgr.campus_official_org_all f
inner join odsmgr.campus_official_organization oo
on f.dept=oo.organization_code
group by  f.organization_level_6,  f.organization_mc_desc ,
oo.campus_desc
```

I've tried several methods, but I can't seem to switch this version of the SQL up to a version that will allow me to nest the data.  Ideally, just for starters, I would like to nest all of the information under unique values for 'INSTITUTION'.  If I can get that much working I am reasonably confident that I will be able to apply the fix to the rest of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Without you data and a more clear description of your expected output it sounds like you want a combination of JSON_OBJECT and JSON_OBJECTAGG, something along the lines of the below (using Oracle CTE to create some dummy data)

```
with INSTITUTION as (select '1' as instId, 'TEST 1' as instName  from dual union select '2', 'TEST 2' from dual),
     ORGANISATION as (select '1' as orgId , '1' as instId, 'ORG 1' as orgName, 'OC1' as orgCode from dual union select '2', '2', 'ORG 2', 'OC2' from dual union select '3', '2', 'ORG 3', 'OC3' from dual)
select JSON_OBJECT('instName' VALUE i.instName, 'ORGS' value (select JSON_OBJECTAGG('org' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('orgName' VALUE orgName, 'orgCode' VALUE orgCode)) FROM ORGANISATION o where o.instId = i.instId )) 
from institution i ;
```

This will give you a JSON payload for each institution with the orgs underneath.... didn't go down to campus ect but you can extend the above....

Payload for institution 1 =

```
{"instName":"TEST 1","ORGS":{"org":{"orgName":"ORG 1","orgCode":"OC1"}}}
```

Payload for institution 2 =

```
{"instName":"TEST 2","ORGS":{"org":{"orgName":"ORG 2","orgCode":"OC2"},"org":{"orgName":"ORG 3","orgCode":"OC3"}}}
```